# How can I convert an animated WebP to a WebM?

Tags: convert, video-conversion, format-conversion, webm, webp

I would like to convert an animated WebP file to a WebM. However, most tools only support converting to an animated WebP but not back, when they support animated WebPs at all: ImageMagick's `convert` does not support animated WebP, `ffmpeg` does not support animated WebP, and `webpmux` only supports extracting a single frame at a time (as far as I can tell).

How can I go about making that conversion?

Comment: FWIW, ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 seems to support converting animated WebP to frames without issue: `identify ./example.webp` to see the frames, then `convert ./example.webp ./example%04d.png`.

Comment: @wchargin Thanks for the tip. I just tried using this method and found that `convert` (v. 6.9.12-98) produced corrupt frames for [an example image](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/animated-webp) whereas `anim_dump` produced the correct result.

Answer (score 11):

Since there does not appear to be any widely-supported way to do it yet:

1. Install the `anim_dump` example utility from [libwebp](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp), since it is not included in the `webp` package.

   1. Clone the repo:`git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libwebp && cd libwebp`.
   2. Force `make` to build `anim_dump`: `echo "bin_PROGRAMS += anim_dump" >> examples/Makefile.am`.
   3. Install libwebp: `./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && sudo make install`.
   4. [Add `/usr/local/lib` to your linker path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12057372/8234919): `echo "/usr/local/lib" |`[`sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/550808/8234919)`&& sudo ldconfig`. Without this, `anim_dump` will not run.
2. Extract the WebP frames to PNGs using `anim_dump`. `mkdir frames && cd frames && anim_dump ../example.webp && cd ..`.
3. Figure out the framerate of the video using `webpmux`: `webpmux -info ../example.webp`. Use about the average duration of the WebP frames as your WebM framerate. If your WebP does not use a consistent framerate, you'll have to manually deal with the durations somehow.
4. Create a [WebM using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39112246/8234919): `ffmpeg -framerate <my-framerate> -i frames/dump_%04d.png example.webm`
5. Clean up: `rm -r frames/`.